# how to click in a webpage hidden button like facebook groups post button using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, desktop-application

hi i tried to using this code and the login part in the code is work right but the post part in the code not working :(
i tried using python 2.7 and 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 and firefox browser last virision and it not work and

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
usr = raw_input('--> ')
pwd = raw_input('--> ')
poo = raw_input('--> ')
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/<group id you are a member in>'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".input.textInput")
elem.send_keys(poo)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".selected")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()
```

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: defined what i cannot understand you ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes the errors come from the last two lines in the code 
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()

Comment: that is the error  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score -1):

In Selenium IDE you can for example call a button if you know its'a value or title:

```
Command   |   click
Target    |   //input[@value='PUT_A_VALUE_HERE' and @title='PUT_A_TITLE_HERE']
```